# Combine Multiple Pandas columns into a Single Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have a DataFrame for which I have multiple columns I want to combine into 1 with several other columns that I want to be duplicated. An example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=60).reshape(6, 10))
df.columns = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4', 'y5']

   x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  y1  y2  y3  y4  y5
0   2   6   9   4   3   8   6   1   0   7
1   1   4   8   7   3   0   5   7   3   1
2   6   7   4   8   1   5   7   7   8   5
3   6   3   4   8   0   8   7   2   3   8
4   8   5   6   1   6   3   2   1   1   4
5   1   3   7   5   1   6   5   3   8   5
```

I would like a nice way to produce the following DataFrame:

```
    x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  y
0    2   6   9   4   3  8
1    1   4   8   7   3  0
2    6   7   4   8   1  5
3    6   3   4   8   0  8
4    8   5   6   1   6  3
5    1   3   7   5   1  6
6    2   6   9   4   3  6
7    1   4   8   7   3  5
8    6   7   4   8   1  7
9    6   3   4   8   0  7
10   8   5   6   1   6  2
11   1   3   7   5   1  5
12   2   6   9   4   3  1
13   1   4   8   7   3  7
14   6   7   4   8   1  7
15   6   3   4   8   0  2
16   8   5   6   1   6  1
17   1   3   7   5   1  3
18   2   6   9   4   3  0
19   1   4   8   7   3  3
20   6   7   4   8   1  8
21   6   3   4   8   0  3
22   8   5   6   1   6  1
23   1   3   7   5   1  8
24   2   6   9   4   3  7
25   1   4   8   7   3  1
26   6   7   4   8   1  5
27   6   3   4   8   0  8
28   8   5   6   1   6  4
29   1   3   7   5   1  5
```

Is there a nice way to produce this DataFrame with Pandas functions or is it more complicated?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `df.melt()`.

```py
df.melt(
    id_vars = ['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5'],
    value_vars = ['y1','y2','y3','y4','y5'],
    value_name = 'y'
).drop(columns='variable')
```

`df.melt()` will have the column called `variable` that has the value for which column it originally came from (so is that row coming from `y1`, `y2`, etc), so you want to drop that as you see above.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought there should be a function for it but couldn't find it.